# Html5 separating audio stream from video stream

Tags: javascript, html, stream, getusermedia

Using userMedia I get a stream that contains both video and audio. 
Is there a way to separate them? Ie out of the one stream get 2 streams one that has only video and the other has only audio?

Comment: This might be better to do server side with ffmpeg or something similar..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`MediaStream` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream/MediaStream) to create new streams from the audio and video tracks:

```
let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true});
audioStream = new MediaStream(stream.getAudioTracks());
videoStream = new MediaStream(stream.getVideoTracks());
```

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/LLLpewcj/).